# Manually connect to Wi-Fi access point (AP) despite preconfigured APs in wpa_supplicant

Tags: wifi, wpa-supplicant, wpa

I have special demands and need to manually control which Wi-Fi access point I connect to on my Linux machine. The machine is a Raspberry Pi running Raspbian (Debian) but I don't think the hardware platform really matters in the contexts of this question.

Now I am using `wpa_supplicant` as my wireless network manager and it auto connects my machine to some AP with its own logic. In `/etc/network/interfaces` I have

```
allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet manual
wpa-roam /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
iface default inet dhcp
```

In `/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf` I have just a few pre-configured APs and their PSK.

I have done some brief search already. `sudo iwconfig wlan0 essid <SSID> key s:<PSK>` did NOT work for me. It did disconnect `wlan0` from the old AP for a few seconds but soon `wlan0` got connected to the old one again. I am wondering if I have made some mistake when executing this, or if `wpa_supplicant` conflicts with manual configuration.

Is it possible that either of these can be realized:

1. It connects to APs identified in `wpa_supplicant` automatically, but I can manually change the one it connects to as long as the new one is in range?
2. I control if it connects to APs identified in `wpa_supplicant` automatically. When I don't want it to, I am able to make it connect to any AP in range.

Comment: Maybe you should just remove `allow-hotplug wlan0`?